# /var/php_sessions not being recognized

Tags: php, joomla, php-ini

I'm trying to set up Joomla as a CMS for a web site I made. 
I have the site hosted with Globat. When I try to install Joomla, I get this message.

> Warning: Unknown:
>   open(/var/php_sessions/sess_cc24fb3a1ba0e66a653237dd88762ac6, O_RDWR)
>   failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning:
>   Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the
>   current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/php_sessions) in
>   Unknown on line 0

I checked the PHP ini file for the php_session line, and it appears to look like it should. Here's the snippet.

```
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I'd get this error? It looks liek the save_path is what it should be.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: I'd assume so, but I'm not really sure. I have limited access to the server info. (it's just a simple web site server plan). The information I have is `Path to PHP:
/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: I'd say contact Globat, have them take a look at the php.ini and make sure that the folder exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if /var/php_sessions/ exists and is writable by your web server user.

Another reason might be that the corresponding partition is out of space.

But most likely it's a hosting issue that you can't solve by yourself, and you will need to ask assistance from your hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on live chat with them now.

Comment: Needed to contact the host to have them enable these settings.

Comment: I had this problem too when my service upgraded PHP, and in the php.ini I just modified the path to store the php sessions to a tmp of my own, and that solved the problem.